# How to build xmpp over web sockets web chat application like gtalk

Tags: javascript, xmpp, websocket, instant-messaging, facebook-chat

How to build xmpp over web sockets web chat application like gtalk using javascript+html or asp.net?
ıt accepts file transfer, video conferencing, private or group chatting. Multiple users and servers can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your chat system to work with google's gtalk, or If you want to create your own chat server and make private system you will need to implement xmpp on javascript,

follow the links that will help you
http://professionalxmpp.com/
https://github.com/maxpowel/jQuery-XMPP-plugin

Comment: I downloaded openfire and connected with sparkweb but ı cound not connect from gab which is in the professional xmpp examples ch06.I tried var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:7070/xmpp-httpbind');    there is no error but could not connect.how can ı connect?

Comment: Hi, I have not used gab ever, I have developed an chat application using _flex_ which works with _openfire_ using xmpp protocols.
But I can say is check out your firewall settings once, and check in openfire admin panel web in Menu server settings, there is an option to enable/disable httpbinding and others related to script syntax.

Comment: I tried
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:7070/xmpp-httpbind/')
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:5080/http-bind/')
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/')
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:5080/xmpp-httpbind/')
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:5222/xmpp-httpbind/')
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://127.0.0.1:5222/http-bind/')
but there is no connection in openfire admin console.I enabled httpbind and I am using windows 7 x64 and closed firewall. what can ı do ,any ideas?

Comment: please try with `http://127.0.0.1:7070/xmpp-httpbind` or `http://127.0.0.1:5280/xmpp-httpbind`

Comment: is there any configuration in openfire admin console I must do

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve your goal:

1. You can build your own chat solution from scratch (build backend solution using [XMPP XEPs](https://xmpp.org/extensions/), etc. and client-side app)
2. To make it easier for you, you can use a ready backend and SDK provided by some BaaS providers. In such way you can concentrate on building client-side solution and its UI while you already have a ready backend and a set of requests to connect to that backend and use it.

You can try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) since it has both chat and video chat. For video chat they have two options: WebRTC peer-to-peer solution and SFU based one.